# toString inside js function returns undefined and 0 value

Tags: javascript, undefined, tostring

I have function I have written for a *Codewars* test:

> Your task is to make a function that can take any non-negative integer
>   as a argument and return it with it's digits in descending order.
>   Descending order means that you take the highest digit and place the
>   next highest digit immediately after it.

Here is my function:

```
function descendingOrder(n) {
  // convert number into string
  var toStr = n.toString();
  console.log("converted to string:");
  console.log(n);

  // split string at "decimal" point
  strArray = toStr.split(".");
  console.log("split string");
  console.log(strArray);

  // create new array from decimal numbers
  strArray.splice(0,1);
  console.log("Array after split: " + strArray);

  // split into array
  for (var i=0; i<strArray.length; i++) {
    var splitStrArray = strArray[i].split("");
  }

  console.log("new split str Array:");
  console.log(splitStrArray);

  // loop array and: 1) convert to number 2) push to new array of numbers
  var numArray = [];
  for (var j=0; j<splitStrArray.length; j++) {
    numArray.push(Number(splitStrArray[j]));
  }

  // sort in descending order
  numArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
  console.log("new array of numbers:");
  console.log(numArray);
}

descendingOrder(1.45312798);
```

---

**1st Problem:**
Finding the result for undefined I received the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at descendingOrder at Object.exports.runInThisContext

I know the undefined value comes from assigning the result of **n.toString** to a variable.

I tried the following:

```
var toStr = '';
toStr = n.toString();
```

But to no avail.

---

**2nd Problem:**
There is an out put value of 0 which is being put through my function

I did certain [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and other questions before posting this one. Any comments or criticism on my logic with regards to the *Codewars* challenge is more than welcome. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I do not receive that error.

Comment: before converting 'n' to string check IF the value is empty or null. if it's UNDEFINED/NULL it will throw an error.

Comment: Neither did when input into the console, it comes from Codewars output. Apologies I should have specified. But It does still return an undefined value for me in the console.

Comment: you aren't passing an integer.

Comment: Why are you splitting this string at decimal point ? This function's argument has to be "a non-negative **integer**"

Comment: Whats's your expected result ?

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White I would never have figured that out. I left the toString function and tried this, but still got undefined:
function descendingOrder(n) {
  // convert number into string
  var input = n;
  var toString = '' + n;
  // var toStr = n.toString();
  console.log("converted to string:");
  console.log(toString);
  console.log(typeof toString);
}
descendingOrder(4.5);

Comment: @RomainDeSaJardim I wanted to convert to string to make it easier to work with the decimal value and the convert back to a number again. I was unsuccessful in using .split() without converting to a string first. There is probably a much better way to all of this

Comment: @AaronMatthews Integer = non decimal numbers. So you don't have to do this function for decimal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does all :

```
function result(n) {
    var digs=[];
    if (n.toString().indexOf('.')>-1) {
        var m=n.toString().slice(0,n.toString().indexOf('.'));
    } else {
        var m=n.toString();
    }
    for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++) {
        digs.push(parseInt(m[i]));
    }
    return parseInt(digs.sort().reverse().join(''));
}
console.log(result(16435.43)) // 65431
console.log(result(16433153)) // 65433311
```

Comment: great bit of code but it needs to take a decimal value :/

Comment: You said "non-negative integer" is the question ?

Comment: I did didn't I perhaps, I'm not understanding the question properly. *up voted* your answer

Comment: Anyway, i added an edit, the new code should work for decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the question, but I thought it could be a lot shorter. You said *non-negative integer* but then use `1.45312798` in your code, so I used your example value. Would not take much to make it work with just an integer (would be a lot shorter).

```js
var n = 1.45312798;

function sortNumb(n) {
    var p = n.toString().split(".");
    var s = (p[1]) ? "."+ p[1].split("").sort().reverse().join("") : "";
    console.log(p[0]+s);
}
sortNumb(n);
```

Comment: Great bit of code @Tigger! Really amazing how you have to think creatively when it comes to writting efficient javascript! More studying!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```js
function descendingOrder(n) {
  console.log(n);

  // convert number into string
  var toStr = n.toString();

  // split string into array
  strArray = toStr.split("");

  var t = strArray.indexOf('.') + 1;

  // get decimal digits
  var newStr = strArray.splice(t);

  // arrange values by descending order
  newStr = newStr.sort().reverse();

  var sortedNo = strArray.splice(0, t).concat(newStr).join('');

  // print the sorted value
  console.log(sortedNo);
}

descendingOrder(1.45312798);
```

Comment: great solution @Pugazh very elegant and neat!

Comment: use `slice` instead of `splice`, or at least, if you use the first `splice` you don't need the second one. and if you change this: `var t = strArray.indexOf('.') + 1 || strArray.length;` it stays consistent with ints

Answer (score 0):

two compact versions with some ES6

```
//a utility
var sortNumericDecending = (a,b) => b-a;

//simple version that works with positive ints
function descendingOrder(n){
    return +String(n).split("").sort(sortNumericDecending).join("");
}

//takes floats and orders the decimal places
function descendingOrder(n){
    var [int, decimals] = String(+n).split(".");
    return decimals? 
        +(int + "." + decimals.split("").sort(sortNumericDecending).join("")):
        n;
}

//or the same without Array destructuring
function descendingOrder(n){
    var parts = String(+n).split(".");
    return parts.length > 1? 
        +(parts[0] + "." + parts[1].split("").sort(sortNumericDecending).join("")):
        n;
}
```

Besides your question, it's not clear anymore wich one you want.